# Using before_save to store a value in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My app has a type, which is carried consistently through the flow and the type is numbered 1, 2, 3 or 4.

In my `application_controller.rb`, I have the following code:

`before_filter :record_type`

and then below that, in `protected`:

```
def record_type
 field should go here = @type
end
```

I'm confused about how to note the field in the `User` table. It is just `User.type = @type`?

Comment: Could you store it in the session? (User.type = @type doesn't make much sense). And why would you want to store the app type in the users table? What's the `type` exactly?

Comment: It's already stored in the session, I've added it to the controller so that :type = @type in User.new, that oughta work, yeah?

Comment: You should explain your end goal more clearly to get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get your particular record you want to edit first. If it goes on the user, if you have a helper method like current_user (which devise and similar authentication systems provide), you can just use that.

You just want to do current_user.type = @type

But this isn't really a before_save with what you have now. If you're trying to store it when you save the User record, move your filter to the User model. Do something like

```
before_save :add_type_to_user

def add_type_to_user
   self.type = your_type_value_here
end
```

How you get your type value to the model will depend on where you're getting it from. You can use a before_filter in application_controller to set a @@ variable. I use this trick sometimes to get the current user when I'm in a model. You just need to make a getter and setter for the @@ variable. THen you'd just do something like:

```
self.type = User.get_current_type
```

or something like that.

I know it's very rough, but I hope this points you in the right direction.